# Based Laplace-Runge-Lenz vector symmetry is there a general relativity equivalent of the Lamb shift?

Tags: general-relativity, quantum-electrodynamics

One can derive the light bending and perihelion shifts of General Relativity as perturbations of Newtonian/Keplerian orbits using the Laplace-Runge-Lenz vector
https://arxiv.org/pdf/gr-qc/9712082.pdf.   Landau and Lifshitz show in Classical Theory of Fields (1975, p. 336) that the Lense-Thirring effect can be derived similarly.  In QED L&L note (1982, p. 128) the 1950 finding of Johnson and Lippmann (M. Johnson and B. Lippmann, Phys. Rev. vol.78 (1950) 329(A)) of a Dirac equation equivalent of the L-R-L vector (that reduces to LRL in the non-relativistic limit) symmetry with respect to which is responsible for the 2S_1/2:2P_1/2 degeneracy which is only lifted by the Lamb shift radiative correction effect.  Is one of the GR effects equivalent to the Lamb shift?

Comment: This isn't amazingly clear - the text can use a good bit of unpacking and de-condensing to make it easier to read and to make it clearer what the core of the question is.